# How do you pass your (optional) arguments to a user-defined-function?

Tags: php, function, coding-style

I mean, how do you pass your arguments to a function?

Do your user function call looks like this:

```
$this->getSomeNumber($firstArg, $secondArg, null);
```

or do you detect how many arguments was passed to the function and then do the job?

I wonder if is there any coding style covering this. And how do other programming languages handle this?

**UPDATE**

Example fot those, who not understand:

```
function doSmth($firstArgument) {
    if(func_num_args() > 1) {
        //do job if second argument was passed
    }
}
```

Second example:

```
function doSmthElse($firstArgument, $secondArgument) {
    if($secondArgument) {
        //do job if second argument was passed
    }
}
```

And then you call it like:

```
doSmth($var, $secondvar) or doSmth($var)

//**OR**

doSmthElse($var, $secondvar) or doSmthElse($var, null)
```

Which is better to use? I mean which do other programmers expect from you?

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  You call a function with as many arguments as it expects...

Comment: I think what you want is overloading

Comment: @Oli, I'm asking about how to write your function, how to expect arguments to be passed to your functions. Whether set optional arguments to null if you don't need this argument to be passed. It's all about coding style.

Comment: @Buddy: Yes, your question makes more sense now that you've said "optional arguments".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the argument is **optional**, specify it normally with a default value:

```
function foo($requiredArg, $optionalArg = null)
```

If the function takes **multiple optional arguments**, specify them explicitly like in the above example.

If the function takes **a variable number of arguments** (for example, such as [sprintf](http://php.net/sprintf)), then use func_get_args & co.

```
/**
 * Specify here as a comment that this function takes a variable amount of args
 */
function doSomethingWithParameters() {
    ...
}
```

If the function takes required parameters *and* a variable amount of parameters, the same approach applies: Specify always required parameters explicitly like in the first example.

Using comments to clarify variable args etc. is always a good idea. It might be an even better idea to use an array instead, but this would probably depend on what you're doing.

Comment: Thank you for clearing this. Is it from php manual or from your expirience?

Comment: Experience, no idea if the manual really even mentions this kind of "best practice" sort of things

Answer (score 0):

You want dollar signs before those args:

```
$this->getSomeNumber($firstArg, $secondArg, null);
```

But if you're really asking about how to use variable numbers of arguments in php, see func_num_args and func_get_args in the help.

Comment: Oh ok now that you have clarified, I would prefer to see you call func_num_args and use if to call different functions depending on whether you have one or two args.